# Visual Studio 2019 won't publish vue.js, says uglify-webpack-plugin path not found

Tags: vue.js

I have created a vue.js project in Windows 10 Visual Studio 2019 from the project template "Basic Vue.js Web Application" using Javascript.

I went to publish the project, and I get the error below.  I have seen various places in Google searches relating to the problem, but not a resolution.

Does anyone know if vue.js publish is working in Visual Studio 2019?

I tried adding a web.config from a blank node js project as suggested in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/157870/cannot-publish-nodejs-web-project-to-file-location.html   but I get the error below : -

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Copying file .\node_modules\.cache\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\3f\9e\eeb908c1d3d1209cf989d88110e80db17761bafb59b6410526f7c88239a213e2b0213f0a0840201e75b12319b3fdcf3196ee1682a2feeab4d0d4314cb32a to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\.\node_modules\.cache\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\3f\9e\eeb908c1d3d1209cf989d88110e80db17761bafb59b6410526f7c88239a213e2b0213f0a0840201e75b12319b3fdcf3196ee1682a2feeab4d0d4314cb32a failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\.\node_modules\.cache\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\3f\9e\eeb908c1d3d1209cf989d88110e80db17761bafb59b6410526f7c88239a213e2b0213f0a0840201e75b12319b3fdcf3196ee1682a2feeab4d0d4314cb32a'.   VuejsApp01  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets   615
```

It is complaining (or seems to be) about uglifyjs-webpack-plugin ?

Comment: hi, any update on your issue? I'm having the same problem as well.

Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\.\node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\b9\a3\ab948b362ebc755f3fcea13613b154279374036d3ddc61c49e426388efc0efff294a895e9bca59b822dc43fe97a8403c78d564af9917ef60ecfd6276d109'.